# Velocity js translateY issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, velocity.js

I have following code to do transitionx

```
     var w = $(window).width()*0.02;

      $('#mChangePassword').velocity({translateX: w},
      {
        duration: 300,
        'complete': function(){
          $('.mSettingsMain').fadeOut(300);
        }
      });
```

Attached GIF how it works in mobile app
http://g.recordit.co/WDCGVFPXsE.gif

**NOTE**: Clicking on the above link is not working somehow, copy pasting image links works.

Here the animation is coming from right to left when I click on button.

I want same animation from bottom to top, I tried using `translateY` but it is not working,

I tried with the following code

```
      var h = $(window).height()*0.02;

      $('#mChangePassword').velocity({translateY: h},
      {
        duration: 300,
        'complete': function(){
          $('.mSettingsMain').fadeOut(300);
        }
      });
```

but it is not working, I want the same animation from that gif "bottom to up" or "slide up".

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When transitioning transforms in Velocity it's best to use forcefeeding and provide units to the property values:

```
$('#mChangePassword').velocity({translateY: [h + 'px', '100%']});
```